# php - Add to cart via mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have simple question. I try to do easy e-shop. All items are listed from database

```
ID|NAME|DESCRIPTION|....|ADD TO CART
```

Id like to make field ADD TO CART after clicking on the icon actually add item to the cart.
So far I have on the page listed everything what I need:

```
Listed items from DB,
user login form,
sessions for users
```

I just like to know if its possible via DB field add item to cart and if it, what I need to do (not exactly full code but info about "make this and than this" would be great.
 
P.S. I don't have any $_session['cart'] so far. 
Thanx for any advice.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a website for concrete programming issues. Questions regarding best practices and so on are more suitable for by example Programmers.

Comment: Yes, it is not complicated even, let me give you a hint: a user can have many items and an item can have many possible buyers (people who put said item in their cart), what kind of relation exists between a user and an item and how do you store it?, for simplicity, we'll leave race conditions and stock restrictions aside for now. Also, this is not a "programming issue" per-sé, but it's still somewhat related and a question I liked because of how it was formulated, regarding what @Aquillo said.

Comment: @Chander 
well I have 2 tables so far Users and Items. Both with primary keys but no forein keys. Relation should be M:M as you mentioned. Storing should be done by sessions. As far as I know i need to add session['cart'] but I`m not sure how to do that with sql field.
Anyway, thanx for your reactions. Gonna try programmers

Comment: @user3037825 Correct, an M:N relation would be what you're looking for, the use of session now lies in whether or not you want to let users who have not logged in to add items to their cart, Robin Van Cauter provided an interesting answer with some insights on your options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I understand your question, so I could be way off with what you are actually looking for, but I'll give it a go;

There are a couple of approaches to this, but they differ in implementation and mechanics of your Cart:

1. **Sessions**: Create a session and store cart items in the session - No account, but cart items will be lost when the user closes the browser
2. **Cookies-only**; store cart items in a cookie - Users don't need an account, but cart is remembered even after closing browser
3. **Database-only**; store a list of items in the database - users would need an account so you can link a Cart database entry with the users account, the cart will be remembered after closing the browser.
4. **Combination of 2 and 3**: You store the cart items in a database, put the unique cart id into a cookie; cart will still be there after closing the browser, without an account and a very small cookie. Some people might ask why this approach, well, if you want to keep track of what people are putting in their carts and derive statistics you should store this information server side.

From your question I would assume you'd like a database oriented approach;
You will need some extra tables accomplish this;

A **carts** table with at least a *cart_id* column, maybe *user_id* if you would go with number 3 and want to link a cart with a specific logged in user.

A **cart_entries** table with a *cart_entry_id column, cart_id and a product_id*.
For every product a user adds to it's cart, an entry is put in this table with the unique cart_id number it belongs too and the product_id number of that product.

Small disclaimer: I am no expert, so there might be better ways of doing this that I am not aware of, I am just providing the approaches I would take myself. And of course there are a more variations on my approaches too depending on what actual practical result you want to get out of it.